# Web request property "URL" is empty

Tags: delphi, http, uri, delphi-xe2, indy10

I'm trying to figure out how to read the *full* URI from a request (`Web.HTTPApp.TWebRequest`). There is a `URL` property, however it returns empty, and I don't see any more properties which could give me this. How can I get the complete URI of the request? This is being used via Indy 10 `TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge`.

For example...

```
http://www.mydomain.com:18500/SomePath/SomeFile.html?n=v&a=b
```

I tried tracking this `URL` property and found that in `IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas` this is being left blank, apparently deliberately...

```
function TIdHTTPAppRequest.GetStringVariable(Index: Integer): AnsiString;
...
  case Index of
    ...
    //INDEX_URL             : Result := AnsiString(FRequestInfo.Document);
    INDEX_URL             : Result := AnsiString(''); // Root - consistent with ISAPI which return path to root
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why `INDEX_URL` returns a blank string. Obviously, it was deliberate, though.

If you look at the `IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas` code more carefully, you will see that `INDEX_URL` used to return `FRequestInfo.Document`, which is the same value that `INDEX_PathInfo` and `INDEX_PathTranslated` both return.  So you could try using a combination of the `TWebRequest.Host`, `TWebRequest.ServerPort`, `TWebRequest.Path...`, and `TWebRequest.Query` properties to recreate the URL you are looking for (minus the protocol, which you will just have to hard-code).

Also, XE+ has a `TWebRequest.RawPathInfo` property which `TIdHTTPAppRequest` implements to return Indy's `TIdHTTPRequestInfo.URI` property value, so you should look at that as well.