# How to rebuild Indy 10 which comes with Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy, indy10, rebuild

In Delphi XE2 I'm using Indy 10. I made a small change to one of the units `IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge` and to take effect, I need to re-build indy. I can't find this in any search, I keep getting results for installing it from scratch - but nothing about re-building what comes with Delphi.

How do I re-build Indy 10?

Comment: Don't. That version of Indy is outdated. Get the modern version - http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx - port your change to it and rebuild it like the links above documents it.

Comment: ...And hopefully the specific problem which I was fixing would be fixed in the later...

Comment: just get indy from the svn : http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/download/svn.en.aspx; Remove built-in Indy from Delphi and add it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas` is included in the Indy release, but it is not actually used by Indy itself.  It is used internally by Embarcadero when using Indy inside of DataSnap, and thus is not compiled into Indy itself in any way. So there is no need to recompile Indy itself (unless you want to upgrade it, but be sure to take note of the warnings in the [install instructions](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx)).  You can submit a bug fix to Indy's developers so it is included in future releases, but that will not address your problem in XE2 since DataSnap cannot be recompiled. But if you are using static linking in your project, you could try simply adding the modified `IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas` file directly into your app.

Comment: Thanks, the modification is a result of my prior question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731304/web-request-property-url-is-empty

Comment: Although DataSnap cannot be rebuilt in XE2, in the later versions of Delphi DataSnap has an Indy adaptor package which CAN be rebuilt.  Might be a good reason to move up to Delphi XE4, jerry.  I don't use DataSnap and I do use the LATEST Subversion Indy code, not the stuff that ships with Delphi. I recommend the same for you Jerry.